# How to convert String in base64 image in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64

In my application i got latitude and longitude.Now on a click on a button i have to upload this co-ordinates into server. If i want to upload a position i have to upload a txt file containing the coordinates in the described format. The text file have to be upload as a Base64 coded stream like a picture file, e.g. jpg or png.

Here is my code:

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"];
str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];


lg= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lattitude is: %.8f", coord.longitude];
ls= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Longitude is: %.8f", coord.latitude];

valueString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@ \n %@",lg,ls,str];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might solve your problem

```
NSString *decodeString = @"Sample Data";
```

Encode String

```
NSData *encodeData = [decodeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [encodeData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"Encode String: %@", base64String);
```

Decode String

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Decode String: %@", base64String);
```

Comment: so file format will be what png or jpeg?

Comment: @user3218052: Base64 is an encoding scheme for arbitrary binary data. It has nothing to do with PNG or JPEG.

Comment: so simply i write ur code it convert and i got output as  Encode String: TGF0dGl0dWRlIGlzOiAwLjAwMDAwMDAwIAogTG9uZ2l0dWRlIGlzOiAwLjAwMDAwMDAwIAogMjAxNC0wNS0wMSAxNDowNTo2MA==

Comment: now i have to send it server so what shoild i do can i pass it as image

Comment: as @MartinR said you can pass any data. I will be converted to binary

Comment: @MartinR i have two parameter one is Filetype and other is content in which file type is like png jpeg and content have encoded string value so if i set filetype=@"png";  and content=base64string then it will work ?

Comment: @JayGajjar  i have two parameter one is Filetype and other is content in which file type is like png jpeg and content have encoded string value so if i set filetype=@"png"; and content=base64string then will it work ?

Comment: just try i dont know what kind of code is written on your server

Comment: @user3218052: Your question is about uploading coordinates in Base64 encoding. I cannot see what that has to do with image types like PNG or JPEG.

Comment: @MartinR please look at my question again its my client requirement so have to do can u please provide me a code by which i can move ahead